# how to use Gaufrette Stream Wrappers?

Tags: symfony, stream, gaufrette

If i have defined as below a stream wrapper in my symfony2 config.yml:

```
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        my_drive:
            local:
                directory: %my_drive_path%
                create:     true
    filesystems:
        user_fs:
            adapter:    my_drive
            alias:      my_drive_filesystem
    stream_wrapper:
        protocol: data
```

how can i use it in my controller for download the file ?

i have something like this:

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse("data://user_fs/" . $key);
```

so i call my file using the addres: `"data://user_fs/"`
haw can i change it to dont use it, couse if i change name in config i will also have to change it in my controller. and i want to manage it only in one file (config)

Answer (score 1):

You can define path as a parameter in your `parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    data_protocol: data
    data_filesystem: user_fs
    data_path: "%data_protocol%://%data_filesystem%/"
```

and get it from container:

```
$path = $this->get('system_container')->getParameter('data_path')
$response = new BinaryResponse($path . $key);
```